# Merge rows in big dataset based on common values

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

I have a 54,000 rows and 500 columns worth of data, but a lot of the values in a specific column "policy number" have the same policy numbers since the data set includes anytime a money value changes (but the most important 100 columns have the same value). (the main data set is named Home)

Example of data set:

```
Total Claim    Claim number  Type of Loss   Date  .....  

$45,000          3500           Fire         2001 ....

$45,000          3500           Fire         2002 ....

$45,000          3500           Water        2001 ....
```

What I want is for all the claims with the same number to be joined together as one row, and if a column has different value, to have them combine with a comma in the middle.

Example of outcome I want:

```
Total Claim    Claim number   Type of Loss   Date.....  

$45,000          3500          Fire, Water    2001, 2002  ...
```

I have tried aggregate, merge and rbind but I think I am coding it wrong since it does not work. Below are all the different lines of code I have tried that have resulted in nothing.

```
# Creating a dataset where all the same policy numbers are together

SamePolicy <- aggregate(Home[,3:446], list(Home[,2]), function(x) paste0(unique(x)))
SamePolciy <- merge(data.frame(Home), by="Claim_Number")
SamePolicy <- merge(Home, Home$Total_Claim, by="Claim_Number")
SamePolicy <- aggregate(.~Home$Claim_Number, df, function(x) paste0(unique(x)))
```

EDIT: I have lots of columns so I do not want to have to specifically call each one to make the edits if that is possible? Also, I want repeats in columns to be deleted so instead of the output being 2001,2002,2001 I just want 2001,2002.

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to use `dplyr` here is one option. Put columns you don't want to collapse into the `group_by` and all remaining columns will be collapsed.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(`Total Claim` = rep(45000, 3),
             `Claim number` = rep(3500, 3),
             `Type of Loss` = c('Fire', 'Fire', 'Water'),
             Date = c(2001, 2002, 2001))

df %>%
  group_by(`Total Claim`, `Claim number`) %>%
  summarize_all(.funs = function(X) paste(unique(X), collapse = ','))
```

Edit: Add an option using column index numbers rather than full column names

```
df %>%
  group_by_at(c(1, 2)) %>%
  summarize_all(.funs = function(X) paste(unique(X), collapse = ','))
```

Comment: I kind of combined both of the comments to fix it! thank you this helped a bunch! ive been stuck on it for a week

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[ , .(`Total Claim` = mean(`Total Claim`),
        `Type of Loss` = paste(unique(`Type of Loss`), collapse = ","), 
        Date = paste(unique(Date), collapse = ",")), by = `Claim number`]
```

It wasn't clear if you want differing money values to be separated by a comma, or if you expect the `Total Claim` value to be the same across `Claim number`. If the values should be the same, then the mean will return the correct result.

This gives us:

```
   Claim number Total Claim Type of Loss      Date
1:         3500       45000   Fire,Water 2001,2002
```

Data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~`Total Claim`,    ~"Claim number",  ~"Type of Loss",   ~Date,  

45000,          3500,           "Fire",         2001, 

45000,          3500,           "Fire",         2002,

45000,          3500,           "Water",        2001 
)
```

Comment: Total Claim is the same number across each distinct policy number so that will be the same.  How is that I can get rid of duplicates in the list for date and type of loss? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just updated the post - you just need to add `unique` before `Type of Loss` and `Date`, so it will only return unique values.

Comment: Thank you! So one more question, I have hundreds of rows after date, is there a way I can use this function to paste the unique values without naming EACH column? I have about 500 columns.

Comment: I'm pretty new to `data.table` so I don't have a solution right now, but I'll work on it when I can. Please update and let me know if you've found a solution!